# wpdb update is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-update

```
Here is the code I am using 

global $wpdb;
$id = $_GET["id"];
$catid=$_POST["catid"];
$year=$_POST["year"];
$amount=$_POST["amount"];

//update
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$data_update = array('catid' => "$catid",'year' => "$year",'amount' => "$amount");
$data_where = array('id' => "id");
$wpdb->update('wp_stats', $data_update, $data_where);   
}
```

I have tried many examples from the forum here and am not getting it to update.

**I figured out the problem:**
no quotes needed around variables in if statement and $ before the id in $data_where.

```
Updated code:


global $wpdb;
$id = $_GET["id"];
$catid=$_POST["catid"];
$year=$_POST["year"];
$amount=$_POST["amount"];

//update
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$data_update = array('catid' => $catid,'year' => $year,'amount' => $amount);
$data_where = array('id' => $id);
$wpdb->update('wp_stats', $data_update, $data_where);   
}
```

Thanks Vlad L your comment made me re-look at the code and find the mistakes.

Comment: not working is a poor description, please tell us the error and give more details

Comment: Unfortunately I am not getting an error in Wordpress. I turned on error in the config file, but nothing useful. This is a plugin that I am working on. My add and delete is working fine just can't seem to get this to update. Is there a way to see more errors in the admin?